# How does IDisposable work with use and return?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, disposable

In F# `async` workflows, we can define a resource that should be cleaned up with the `use` keyword.

But how does `use` interact with `return`?

For example, given this code:

```
let createResource = async {
  use r = Resource ()

  do! operationThatMightThrow r

  return r
}

async {
  use! r = createResource

  printfn "%O" r
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Where will the calls to `Resource.Dispose` happen?

How can I design this so that the `r` is always cleaned up (even if `operationThatMightThrow` throws)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually have two solutions.

The first solution is actively capturing the exception, manually disposing the disposable object, and re-throwing the exception:

```
let createResource = async {
    let r = new Resource ()
    try do! operationThatMightThrow r
    with e -> (r :> IDisposable).Dispose(); raise e
    return r
}
```

The second solution is to use a continuation function that will have access to the disposable object before the async returns:

```
let createResource cont = async {
    use r = new Resource ()
    do! operationThatMightThrow r
    return cont r
}

async {
    let! x = createResource (fun r -> printfn "in cont: %O" r)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They will occur before the value is returned from the computation expression, semantically they will happen in a `finally` block. If you want to look at the source of the generated using statement, you can find it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L610-L615). It effectively generates an access-controlled dispose function that calls `Dispose()` on the resource you pass in, then makes an asynchronous try-finally block with that function in the finally clause.